# Extra action in Django rest framework returning not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add extra actions to an existing system, but when I call that endpoint I get the following error:

Page not found at /api/user/5/mood

Here is the code:

views.py

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    # pagination_class = PostLimitOffsetPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = User.objects.all()

        page_size = 'page_size'
        if self.request.GET.get(page_size):
            pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = self.request.GET.get(page_size)
        else:
            pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = 10
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(email__icontains=query) |
                Q(username__icontains=query)
            )

        return queryset_list.order_by('-id')

    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def mood(self, request, pk=None):
    return Response({'mood': '1'})
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    UserListAPIView, UserCreateAPIView,
    UserDetailAPIView, UserDeleteAPIView,
    UpdateAPIView
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserListAPIView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('create', UserCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='user-creator'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', UserDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', UserDeleteAPIView.as_view(), name='user-destroyer'),
]
```

Comment: `@action` decorator is for `ViewSet`, not for generic views such as `ListAPIView`.

Comment: @Alp totally missed that! tnx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Alp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5543574/alp), @action decorator is for ViewSet, not for generic views such as ListAPIView. After the change, the path needs to be updated to  `path('', UserListAPIView.as_view({'get': 'mood'}), name='user-mood')`